# question regarding for-loop created for expected value

Tags: r, for-loop

I have created a loop for a probability distribution that allows me to store a list of expected values of a sum of money:

```
E.value.tickets.df<- data.frame( )
P.value.at.each.level<- NA
G.val.per.ticket.win<- NA
E.val<- NA
Number.of.draws.year = 4032
Raffle.tickets.cap = 4000000000

for (i in 1:10000) {

  E.val.year<- (dbinom( x= i, size = 10000, prob = (Number.of.draws.year/Raffle.tickets.cap)))
 
  G.val.year<- (i*200)
 
  P.value.at.each.level[i]<- E.val.year
  G.val.per.ticket.win[i]<- G.val.year
  E.val[[i]]<- (P.value.at.each.level[i]*G.val.per.ticket.win[i])
  E.value.tickets.df<- data.frame(E.val)
  
}

sum(E.value.tickets.df[ , 1])
```

However, now instead of just using '10,000' as my value and running for just that one entry (The 10,000), I wanted to test multiple at the same time, more specifically a `seq()` of 100000 entries. However, using the loop a hundred thousand times is not very efficient ( and the environment with that many crashes) So I was wondering if there was a way to make my loop for that sequence and store each result of the  `(P.value.at.each.level[i]*G.val.per.ticket.win[i])`  as an individual column of the dataframe instead.

Thank you so much for your help and time :)

Comment: What are the values of `Number.of.draws.year` and `Raffle.tickets.cap`?

Comment: number.of.draws.yerar = 40320 and Raffle.tickets.cap = 4000000000